# Get-NetAdapter will not work

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-networking

The first simple example using `Get-NetAdapter` in `Get-Help` from Microsoft will not work on my machine. Any suggestions?

```
PS C:\Users\lit> Get-NetAdapter -Name *
Get-NetAdapter : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapter -Name *
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetAdapter:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter) [Get-NetAdapter], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetAdapter

PS C:\Users\lit> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1066
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.1066
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

It appears that I have the NetAdapter module on my system.

```
PS C:\Users\pwatson> Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like '*NetAdapter*'}

    Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetAdapter                          {Disable-NetAdapter, Disable-NetAdapterBinding, Disable-NetAdapterChecksumOffload, Disable-NetAdapt...
```

I finally got to see all of the ExportedCommands, but Get-NetAdapter is not among them.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like '*NetAdapter*'} | Select-Object -Property {$_.ExportedCommands} | Format-Custom
```

Based on Seth's answer, I have:

```
C:\Users\pwatson>winmgmt /verifyrepository
WMI repository verification failed
Error code:     0x80041003
Facility:       WMI
Description:    Access denied
```

I am going to accept Seth's answer and post a new question about permission settings.

Comment: Since I do not know of any tools to customize PowerShell, I do not know that I have used any. What are some of those popular tools that I might have come across? Mostly, I have just been doing Windows Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-NetAdpater` would not be a module but rather a command. You would need to run `Get-Command` instead of `Get-Module`. Furthermore if you carefully read the exception in the first case, it's Metadata exception. It's telling you it can't read the backend data structure. `0x80041010` seems to be the code for `invalid class` returned by WMI. So either your WMI might be damaged ([this might help](https://support.quest.com/vworkspace/kb/88861)) or it might be that you have insufficient permissions. The latter is way more unlikely than the first.

From the above link in order to rebuild you could try:

```
1. winmgmt /verifyrepository
If the result is shown as inconsistent, go to step 2
2. winmgmt /salvagerepository
3. winmgmt /verifyrepository - to check again wmi repository had been repaired successfully
```

I'm leaving the more advanced solution out. As this should help you to verify whenever your WMI might be damaged.

Answer (score 2):

Network Setup Service must be Running for "Get-NetAdapter" command to return anything in PowerShell.